# Input Data Based on Another Input - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wonder is there a way for me to input data based on another input? Here's my code, but it's just throw an error which said, "**Attempt to read property "id_spp" on string.**"

```
Pembayaran::create([
        'id_petugas' => $request->id_petugas,
        'nisn' => $selectedSiswa = $request->nisn,
        'tgl_bayar' => $request->tgl_bayar,
        'id_spp' => $selectedSiswa->id_spp,
        'jumlah_bayar' => $request->jumlah_bayar
    ]);
```

Comment: You are assigning `$selectedSiswa` the value of `$request->nisn`, it could be a bug but difficult to tell without context.

Comment: @YudizSolutions It's seemed like $selectedSiswa haven't been created bcs it's in same state